# Add drop shadow to one side only

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying add a drop shadow to the bottom of a shape only, I have tried playing around with the x and y offset, though that doesn't quite do it, I have also tried using a clipping mask around the shape but for some reason the clipping mask had no affect on the drop shadow.

Is there something obvious I have missed, appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: I have no issues using the clipping mask for this...

Comment: I did try a clipping mask initially, for some reason the layer style (drop shadow) didn't get clipped, is that normal behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Y** moves the blur vertically. A negative Y offset moves the blur upward, a positive Y offset moves the blur downward.
- **X** moves the blur horizontally. A negative X offset moves the blur right, a positive X offset moves the blur left.
- The **Blur** value controls how large the blur is. It is always 50% behind the object and 50% outside the object. So, a blur value of 10px, puts 5px under the edge of the object and 5px outside the edge of the object.

In most instances you will get a blur which is seen on the sides, even if the X value is set to 0. This is because the object is *contracted* by half the blur value, then blurred. So it kind of "leaks" out on the sides. You can't use negative values for the blur amount, so this *always* occurs with the Drop Shadow effect unless your blur value is so small (1 or 2px) that the "bleeding" on the sides is merely unnoticeable).

[image]

If you want a shadow which *only* appears on the bottom a black to transparent gradient may work better.

Add a new fill and move it below the existing fill in the **Appearance Panel**. Then with the new fill highlighted choose `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` to move the fill downward as far as you'd like.  Then just set that new fill to be a gradient going from 100% black 100% opaque to 100% black 0% opaque. You end up with a graduated shadow, with sides that do *not* bleed out. In addition, this method keeps *everything* vector so there aren't any embedded raster images this way (unless you flatten or export the file of course).

[image]

Another option is to use a solid fill color for the second fill, transform it, then use `Effect > Stylize > Feather` on the secondary fill. Feather will *only blur inward* so it won't create the bleeding effect on the sides.

[image]

I tend to prefer the gradient method above because it allows for more control over the shadow drop off, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks. Can't wait to try that.